# How do you fit background/imgs properly with css/html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, size

I'm creating this site on Django and am having trouble with the dimensions of a lot of the elements. On all of the pages, I have a left and right margin spanning col-sm-1 with background: black.

In style.css, I've searched a few solutions but nothing fixes the problem 100%. If I use height: 100%, it shows a skinny slab of black at the top of each margin. I didn't want to put exact pixels because I feel relative sizes will make the site easier to view across platforms. If I put height: 100vh, it covers the height I want, but it doesn't cover properly on long pages with scrollers and leaves a lot of white space.

How do you make the background-color/size of a div extend the whole page(scrollable or not), without having it extend its boundaries? Is there also a way to do this with images so it can stretch? I tried background-size: cover for images, but it extended the col-sm-1 boundary and doesn't cover the bottoms of longer pages that scroll.

the html:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 leftright-margins">
  </div>

<!--Main section-->
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10" id="main_section">
    {% block navbar %}
      {% navbar %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 leftright-margins">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.leftright-margins {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;

}
```

It does alright for a singular page right now, but I have a few pages that displays a table that spans a big height. After the initial screen, if I scroll down, the sides are empty white.

edit:

I figured out the images seemed to overlap because I didn't set the min-height for the main section's container. I still am having trouble adjusting the height of the img/background div so that it covers the whole size of the scrolling page.

edit2:

Found a simple solution with javascript. I think I was over complicating the problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var dynamic = $(document).height();
  var static = $('.leftright-margins');
  static.css({
    'min-height': dynamic,
    'max-height': dynamic,
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle or some code here?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margins on the < body > tag, instead of simply < div >isions within it.  This should apply to the entire document.  If that doesn't work, try adjusting the < html > element.  Someone with more experience will correct me, I'm sure, but working with those two tags can help larger documents.

Answer (score 0):

Body,container-fluid{margin:0;padding:0;} there is default padding and margin use in bootstrap ,may be this cause issue and instead of white space , you use background color black on body vice verse , I am not conform but try it share image if you can